# Autogenerate=true doesn't set the id of inserted entity in Room

Tags: insert, entity, primary-key, android-room, auto-generate

I'm inserting entities with my RoomDAO and I can get the autogenerated id back:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.ABORT)
long insert(Category category);
```

But Category.id is not automatically set after insert() call:

```
Category cat = new Category();
long newId = dao().insert(cat);
// newId is a new id, 63 for instance
// cat.id is still 0
```

I must explicitely load the entity again via the Dao to see a not null id:

```
cat = dao().getCategoryById(newId);
// cat.id is 63
```

The model:

```
@Entity(tableName = "category")
public class Category {
  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  public int id;
  ...
```

Is it possible to instruct Room to populate `cat.id` immediately? Or am I using a wrong pattern?

Comment: I too have the same question. Basically ID is returned, but not populated in the entity. Same happens when I do a select-all. IDs are not populated. @ntucci, BTW you got any solution to this?

Comment: @RamanSrinivasan no, I found no solution, except that using a class, between my logic and the DAO, for loading/filling the entity.